# How are Kotlin Array's toList and asList different?

Tags: java, arrays, list, reference, kotlin

The Kotlin `Array` class offers `asList()`, `toList()`, and `toMutableList()` methods. The first two methods both return a `List` and are described in the [Kotlin reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/index.html)  as follows:

- `asList()` returns a `List` that wraps the original `Array`.
- `toList()` returns a `List` containing all elements [of the original `Array`].

These methods *appear* interchangeable. How do these two methods differ in practice?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### TL;DR

The list created with `asList` keeps a reference to the **original** `Array`.
The list created with `toList`/`toMutableList` is backed by a **copy** of the original `Array`.

### Explanation

**asList**

The `asList` function creates a list that *reuses* the *same* `Array` instance, which implies that changes to the original array also have impact on the `List`:

```
val arr = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val l1 = arr.asList()

arr[0] = 4
println(l1) // [4, 2, 3]
```

**toList**

This isn't the case for `toList`/`toMutableList` since the array is *copied*:

```
val arr = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val l2 = arr.toList()

arr[0] = 4
println(l2) // [1, 2, 3]
```

The Kotlin source code can be found [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/libraries/stdlib/src/generated/_Arrays.kt).

Answer (score 11):

Basically `asList()` still maintains a reference to the original `Array`. That means mutations to that list will also mutate the underlying `Array`.

`toList()` is simply copying the values of the `Array` into a new `List`, but there is no lingering link afterwards.

For most use-cases, they probably are interchangeable. `asList()` will likely have slightly better performance (since it isn't performing a copy) and `toList()` will be a "safe" copy against unexpected mutations.