# Kotlin : null cannot be value of non null type kotlin

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, kotlin

How to assign null value to `ArrayList` in Kotlin?

I am trying to add null value to my custom `ArrayList`
like that

```
var mList = ArrayList<CustomClass>()
mList.add(null)
```

In java its possible but how can I achieve this in Kotlin?
I am getting

> null cannot be value of non null type kotlin

I need to insert **null** value for doing load more functionality in RecyclerView

Comment: Kotlin's [null docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) are a good place to start.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Then you have to write it in this way.

```
var mList = ArrayList<CustomClass?>()
mList.add(null)
```

You have to add a `?` after the type in ArrayList because `?` allows us to put a null value.

Answer (score 17):

Kotlin’s type system differentiates between nullable types and non-null types. For example, if you declare a simple `String` variable and let the compiler infer its type, it cannot hold `null`:

```
var a = "text" //inferred type is `String`
a = null //doesn’t compile!
```

On the other hand, if you want a variable to also  be capable of pointing to `null`, the type is explicitly annotated with a question mark:

```
var a: String? = "text"
a = null //Ok!
```

In your example, the `ArrayList` is declared with the generic type `CustomClass`, which is not nullable. You need to use the nullable type `CustomClass?` instead. Also, you can make use of [Kotlin’s standard library functions for creating instances of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411459/8073652), preferably **read-only** ones.

```
var mList = listOf<CustomClass?>(null)
```

Otherwise `mutableListOf()` or also `arrayListOf()` will help you.