# How to create List from Set in Kotlin?

Tags: collections, kotlin

Suppose I have a set with elements. How to create List of the same elements? I see methiods `asSequence` and `asIterable`, but no `asList`, why?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The function you're looking for is called [`toList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html):

```
val set: Set<Int> = setOf(1,2,3)
val list: List<Int> = set.toList()
```

Comment: Wow! Why is it sometimes "as" and sometimes "to"?!

Comment: `as` most often implies that the object is being reused in the created instance. Take `asList` and `toList` for arrays as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48411392/how-are-kotlin-arrays-tolist-and-aslist-different/48411459#48411459